# How to reduce the auxiliary memory of the below two binary tree related problems : [ grand parent and uncle related problems ]

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, memory-efficient

I was asked to solve a binary tree traversal related problem recently where the aim is to find sum of all nodes in a binary tree where node is odd and its uncle is also odd. I came with a solution as below which is O(n) in algorithmic complexity ( 1 time full traversal of the tree ) and auxillary memory usage which is equal to O(h). If and only if the binary tree happends to be BST and height balanced then it can be argued that the auxillary memory complexity will be O(log(n)).

My solution is a variation on the path identification of all root to leaf problem. This problem and its solution can be found here.

**https://github.com/anandkulkarnisg/BinaryTree/blob/main/set2/rootleaf.cpp**

The solution to the odd node with odd uncle is given here.

**https://github.com/anandkulkarnisg/BinaryTree/blob/main/set5/sumodduncle.cpp**

The interviewer agreed that the algorithmic complexity is obvious as one traversal is definitely needed and it is O(n). But he argued that the auxiliary memory complexity can be designed much better than O(h) and he did not tell what the approach was. I have been thinking about this for 2 weeks now and haven't got a better solution yet.

I cleared the interview btw and was offered a role that I am considering now, but I still don't know what the better approach to auxiliary memory tuning is here. Can it be O(1) sounds not possible until somehow we keep track at every node only the parent and grandparent which is then O(1).is that possible?

Comment: (There has been [Morris traversal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Morris_in-order_traversal_using_threading), temporarily contorting the tree.)

Comment: But if you keep additional tracking of parent then the auxillaary memory is O(n) and O(n) is worser than O(h) since h=log(n) and in most cases it is not a degenerate tree i.e h=n.

Comment: Since you have to visit every node to count uncles, your starting tree either needs to have parent pointers, or be modifiable to use Morris traversal. No auxiliary space and O(n) time is possible with Morris traversal, as each node can count how many of its odd grandchildren have odd uncles in O(1) time each as you do an in-order traversal. It's still pretty tricky, as you're updating the tree and counting at the same time.

Comment: that makes some sense, At every parent node in iteration all i need to keep a track is its parent ( rest of children are available already ). valid point...

Comment: I did a solution without the array in recursive call via making sure i pass parentNode along with current node in consideration. It seems to work without any fixed amount of array memory. The code is updated and tested as well. But i have a  obvious question on the stack in the code , which is although you dont use a reserved pool of array or ADT to store your recursive call is still anyway holding all function calls and variable so it is consiming O(n) proportional memory anyway. I guess this is the best one can do since you cant solve BT problems without recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/anandkulkarnisg/BinaryTree/blob/main/set5/sumodduncle.cpp In this code module the solution using the below invocation...

**long sumAlt=findSumOddUncle(uniqueBstPtr);**

Is the O(1) solution because all variables are passed via pointer and only the sum is passed which accumulates the total in recursive calls. Tested and works as expected.